# How to create and populate an array programmatically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a multi dimensional array programmatically. But when i push an object into the array it gets pushed into all indexes in the array. Why is this happening

Here's a simple demo

```
let postTest = new Array(4).fill([]);
postTest[0].push({key: 'value', anotherKey: 'value'});
console.log(postTest);
```

Comment: That's because you fill the array with the same *reference*.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler could you provide a link or explain in more detail please?

Comment: @Reece https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Array.from` instead, [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) copies the reference of object on all places so any change at one place will reflect at all places

```js
let postTest = Array.from({length: 4}, ()=> []);

postTest[0].push({ key: 'value',  anotherKey: 'value' });

console.log(postTest);
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [`fill()` method docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

> **value**
>   Value to fill the array with. (Note all elements in the array will be this exact value.)

You can fix this issue, by assigning the empty array to individual index using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) so that there no reference issue like:

```js
let postTest = new Array(4).fill().map(x=>[]);
postTest[0].push({key: 'value', anotherKey: 'value'});
console.log(postTest);
```

You can also, try:

```js
let postTest = [...Array(4)].map(x=>[]);
postTest[0].push({key: 'value', anotherKey: 'value'});
console.log(postTest);
```